# when i put (DateTime) in front of a DataBinder.eval what does that do

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i put (DateTime) in front of a DataBinder.eval what does that do, and what other functions can i put infornt of a databinder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just cast the object returned by the `.Eval` method, to the `DateTime` type. If casting is impossible, an `InvalidCastException` will be thrown. Regarding functions that you can put in front of `DataBinder.Eval`, you can put pretty much anything. However, the majority of this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is casting the data from `object` which `Eval` is returning to a `DateTime`.

```
// If the cast fails you will get an exception
DateTime dt = (DataTime)(DataBinder.Eval("yourfield"));

// If the cast fails you will get null.
DateTime? dt = DataBinder.Eval("yourfield") as DateTime?;

// You could also do which will throw an exception if it fails as well. 
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval("yourfield"));
```

For more information on casting see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(VS.80).aspx).